# Error with Kieran Healy's emacs starter kit

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have installed Kieran Healy's emacs [social sciences starter kit](https://github.com/kjhealy/emacs-starter-kit). I have changed the name of the file kjhealy.org to ljs.org (as per his instructions). The starter kit settings seem to load, but I get the following error.

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading 
‘/Users/ljs/.emacs.d/init.el’:

File error: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, ob-shell
```

When I open emacs with the --debug-init files, I get the following:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function package-initialize)
(package-initialize)
eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/ljs/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  
; Reading at buffer position 403
load-with-code-conversion("/Users/ljs/.emacs.d/init.el" 
 "/Users/ljs/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/Users/ljs/.emacs.d/init" t t)
#[nil "^H\205\276^@   \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202A^@ 
\311=\2033^@\312\307\313\314#\203#^@\315\202A^@\312\307\313\$
command-line()
normal-top-level()
```

Any help with this greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hm I thought that had been fixed ages ago. I'm not sure what it is in `ob-shell` that  triggers this error ... Some users have reported that changing `(shell . t)))` to `(sh . t)))` on line 105 of `starter-kit-org.org` will fix this problem (whereas for me it causes it ...)

Comment: That change works. Just one other question. Somewhere in the code you have turned the toolbar off. Where would I find that?

Comment: Look for `tool-bar-mode`: the default is `t`, the toolbar is turned off if you set it to `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying reason for this problem is that the file `ob-sh.el` was renamed to `ob-shell.el` and the corresponding babel language became `shell`. That happened in version 8.2.5 (more precisely, it's commit 583e7ab17:

```
$ git describe 583e7ab17
release_8.2.4-332-g583e7ab17
```

so 332 commits after 8.2.4).

So if your version of emacs is 8.2.4 or earlier, you have to use `sh` as the babel language and load the file `ob-sh.el`. For 8.2.5 and later (including the current version that is distributed with emacs), you have to use `shell` as the babel language and load the file `ob-shell.el`.

Hope that clarifies.